# MySQL after update trigger doesn't work correctly when a new order stored

Tags: jquery, mysql, database, stored-procedures, triggers

I created a trigger for copying rows from Woocommerce tables into a destination table with the name "serialized_data".
it works correctly after insert time/event mode when new order stores, but I also need to copying data when each "order_status" changed from "wc-pending" to "wc-processing";
I used the same trigger after update time/event mode too but doesn't work correctly
so, always the last order will not copy until a new row inserts to the table

```
Trigger: wp_posts.after_post_insert

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS after_post_insert;

DELIMITER |

CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost' TRIGGER after_post_insert
  AFTER INSERT
  ON wp_posts
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO pickup.serialize_data (id,order_id,date_modified,status,product_name,product_image,qty,sku,total_items)

    SELECT
  B.order_item_id AS id,
  A.ID AS order_id,
  A.post_modified_gmt AS date_modified,
  A.post_status AS status,
  B.order_item_name AS product_name,
  E.guid AS product_image,
  F.meta_value AS qty,
  G.meta_value AS sku,
  H.num_items_sold AS total_items

FROM wp_posts A


  INNER JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_items B
    ON A.ID = B.order_id
    
  INNER JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta C
    ON B.order_item_id = C.order_item_id

  INNER JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta F
    ON B.order_item_id = F.order_item_id AND F.meta_key = ('_qty')
    
    
  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta D
    ON C.meta_value = D.post_id

  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta G
    ON C.meta_value = G.post_id AND G.meta_key = ('_sku')       

    
  INNER JOIN wp_posts E
    ON D.meta_value = E.ID
    
  INNER JOIN wp_wc_order_stats H
    ON B.order_id = H.order_id
    
WHERE A.post_type = 'shop_order'
AND A.post_status = 'wc-processing'
AND C.meta_key IN ('_product_id')
AND D.meta_key IN ('_thumbnail_id')
AND F.meta_key IN ('_qty')
AND G.meta_key IN ('_sku');

  END|

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Is it works when you are inserting wp_posts and not when your updating `post_status` in wp_posts table?

Comment: it works when a new record added to wp_post table where conditions are post_status='wc-processing' and post_type ='shop_order'

Comment: I have a suspicion that woocommerce does a delete then an insert when performing "update" operations.  I'm trying to debug a similar issue myself with the wp_wc_order_stats when I want to track when an order status changes to completed.